# Having trouble loading angular pagination dependency into module

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I am trying to load the angular pagination dependency 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination' into my module, but when I do I am getting a "failed to instantiate module marbleApp due to:..." error. My app was working correctly before trying to add this dependency. Here is some code.

app.js:

```
var marbleApp = angular.module("marbleApp", ['ui.router', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

granite.html:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">   
        <div class="col m3" dir-paginate="material in graniteStuff | itemsPerPage: 20">
          <a href="{{ url }}"><div class="card">
            <div class="card-image small">
                <img src="">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <p>{{ material.material_name }}</p>
              <p>{{ material.material_country_of_origin }}</p>
            </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>

    <div ui-view></div>

    <dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
```

The full error in the console reads as follows:

"Failed to instantiate module marbleApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularUtils.directives.dirPagination due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

I can't find any syntax errors, and I'm pretty sure I am following the docs correctly. Any thoughts?

Docs: https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination#basic-example

Here is an update. I changed my app.js code and was able to add the angularUtils dependency, and now my app works again. But, the pagination feature does not work on the view, and instead of repeating the database results, it simply renders one of the items... No errors. What broke?

app.js

```
angular.module("marbleApp", ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

var marbleApp = angular.module("marbleApp", ['ui.router']);
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">   
        <div class="col m3" dir-paginate="material in graniteStuff | itemsPerPage: 20">
          <a href="{{ url }}"><div class="card">
            <div class="card-image small">
                <img src="">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <p>{{ material.material_name }}</p>
              <p>{{ material.material_country_of_origin }}</p>
            </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>

    <div ui-view></div>

    <dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
```

Comment: What is your JS files sequence. Check that.

Comment: I have almost everything in one app.js file. I think you may be right, but I don't even know what to look for, which is why I don't have everything separated like it should be ha

Comment: Place **angularUtils.directives.dirPagination** module code before your **marbleApp** module code

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to help, but not complete yet. Added update above...

Comment: Can you provide  any Plunkr/JSFiddle of your problem?

Comment: I don't think so because I'm working with a local database to serve back the data, and to be honest, I'm not sure how to take the files and put them into plunkr or JSFiddle... I know that my code renders the data into the separate view(with its own state) correctly with ng-repeat, but the problem occurs when I switch ng-repeat for dir-paginate, which instead of repeating through all the data, it simply renders 1 'item', and renders it incorrectly (without the $scope data)...

Answer (score 1):

Wow, after much hair pulling I solved the issue! @arun you were on the right path... the code to inject the dependency needed to be written as follows:

```
angular.module("marbleApp", []);


var marbleApp = angular.module("marbleApp", ['ui.router', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

Still not clear why. I think that because angular needs to first instantiate the original module "marbleApp", it needs to be able to find it first, without any dependencies...

Anyway, I appreciate the ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/37SLQVLQlb9LDKUbfwbC?p=preview. Created sample based on your JSON. And why

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

is outside of controller?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

app.controller('PaginateController', function($scope) {
  $scope.url = "www.example.com"
  $scope.graniteStuff = [
    {
      'material_name':'sample1',
      'material_country_of_origin':'IN'
    },
    {
      'material_name':'sample2',
      'material_country_of_origin':'US'      
    },
    {
       'material_name':'sample2',
      'material_country_of_origin':'AUS'    
    },
    {
      'material_name':'sample4',
      'material_country_of_origin':'IN'
    },
    {
      'material_name':'sample5',
      'material_country_of_origin':'US'      
    },
    {
       'material_name':'sample6',
      'material_country_of_origin':'AUS'    
    },
        {
      'material_name':'sample7',
      'material_country_of_origin':'IN'
    },
    {
      'material_name':'sample8',
      'material_country_of_origin':'US'      
    },
    {
       'material_name':'sample9',
      'material_country_of_origin':'AUS'    
    },
    {
      'material_name':'sample10',
      'material_country_of_origin':'IN'
    },
    {
      'material_name':'sample11',
      'material_country_of_origin':'US'      
    },
    {
       'material_name':'sample12',
      'material_country_of_origin':'AUS'    
    },
    ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="pagitation.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="PaginateController">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">   
        <div class="col m3" dir-paginate="material in graniteStuff | itemsPerPage: 3">
          <a href="{{ url }}"><div class="card">
            <div class="card-image small">
                <img height=50px src="">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <p>{{ material.material_name }}</p>
              <p>{{ material.material_country_of_origin }}</p>
            </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>

    <div ui-view></div>

    <dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add further line in your controller...
to load the dependencies the controller must have the folder which you need to require 
require('angular-utils-pagination');